# How to return all documents where an array field's size is greater than a given number?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('56a77bfae0ce9f6a738cb2b7'),
    "nameIdentity": [
        {
            "givenNameOne": "LATANYA",
            "givenNameThree": "BIZOR",
            "lastName": "BIZOR",
            "sourceReferenceId": [
                {
                    "sourceReferenceId": "56a77bfae0ce9f6a738cb2b5",
                    "sourceName": "A"
                },
                {
                    "sourceReferenceId": "56a77bfae0ce9f6a738cb2b5",
                    "sourceName": "B"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

nameIdentity is an array and sourceReferenceId is an nested array inside nameIdentity. I am trying to get the documents whose sourceReferenceId size is greater than 2.
I used i aggregation like this :

```
db.entity.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            nameIdentity_count: {$size: "$nameIdentity.sourceReferenceId"}
         }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
            "nameIdentity_count": { "$gte": 2 }
         }
    }
   ]
)
```

this is not working as expected, it gives the document even with one soureReferenceId.Can anyone tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: do you mean array length more than 2 ? `I am trying to get the documents whose sourceReferenceId size is greater than 2`

Comment: Is `nameIdentity` one element array? If it's not what do you want to do if there is  a sub-documents where `sourceReferenceId` size is `$lt` 2? What is the expected result of your query?

Comment: @styopdev yes i mean the array length

Comment: @user3100115 name identity is a one element array. if the size is $lt 2 just ignore. Only display those docs whose array size is $gt2

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli Can you please edit you question and explicitly add the fact that `nameIdentity` is one element array.  I also I believe that you have a design problem there because having a field where the value is always one element array doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 19):

You need to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator. Also you don't need aggregation for this if all you want is `find()` those documents where "sourceReferenceId" size is greater than `2`

```js
db.collection.find( { "nameIdentity.sourceReferenceId.2": {  "$exists": true } } )
```

But if you really need to aggregate your data then:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "nameIdentity.sourceReferenceId.2": {  "$exists": true } } } 
])
```

Also you have a design problem because having a field where the value is always one element array doesn't make any sense. You should consider to change your document structure so that it looks like this:

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId('56a77bfae0ce9f6a738cb2b7'),
    "givenNameOne": "LATANYA",
    "givenNameThree": "BIZOR",
    "lastName": "BIZOR",
    "sourceReferenceId": [
        {
            "sourceReferenceId": "56a77bfae0ce9f6a738cb2b5",
            "sourceName": "A"
        },
        {
            "sourceReferenceId": "56a77bfae0ce9f6a738cb2b5",
            "sourceName": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

And use the following queries depending on what you're trying to do.

```js
db.collection.find( { "sourceReferenceId.2": {  "$exists": true } } )
```

or

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "sourceReferenceId.2": {  "$exists": true } } } 
])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how the query will be used:

```
db.<collection>.find( {<column> : {$exists:true}, $where:'this.<column>.length > 1'})
```

`<collection>`: Your collection

`<column>`: The name of your column

Comment: This doesn't work. I got "Error: Can't use $where with Array."

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$expr` along with `$size`.

```
db.collection.find({"$expr":{$gt:[{$size:"$items"},0]}})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `$size` to get the size of items array and `$gt` to compare the size of items array to 0.

```
db.collection.find({"items":{$gt:[{$size:"items"},0]}})
```

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use $gt with the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/). Return all documents where field "items" has lengths greater then one:

```
db.collection.find({"items": {$gt: {$size: 1}}})
```